# Mask UIView (UICollectionView) correctly

Tags: ios, swift, svg, uikit, uibezierpath

Ok, I need to mask a horizontal `UICollectionView`so it looks like a ribbon. My web dev counterpart got it done with an SVG that he used as a masking layer.

Here is my current situation:[image]

And here is what I need (Photo from our web app):[image]

Small detail in image spacing aside, I have an SVG like this:
[image]

Which I can successfully convert into UIBezierPath code (Paintcode):

```
let pathPath = UIBezierPath()
pathPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 0))
pathPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 162.02, y: 3.8), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 2.1), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 72.57, y: 3.8))
pathPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 324, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 251.48, y: 3.8), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 324, y: 2.1))
pathPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 324, y: 150.2))
pathPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 162.02, y: 154), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 324, y: 152.3), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 251.48, y: 154))
pathPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 150.2), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 72.57, y: 154), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 152.3))
pathPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.17), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 148.1), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.17))
pathPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
UIColor.lightGray.setFill()
pathPath.fill()
```

Now what do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `mask` property of your UICollectionView by setting it to a view whose alpha channel indicates what part of the UICollectionView you want to mask out.  In outline it will probably be something like:

```
// If you don't have a custom subclass of UICollectionView... you can handle the resize in the
// UICollectionViewController or whatever view contoller is handling your view.
//
// If you do have a custom subclass of UICollectionView... you could do something similar 
// in layoutSubviews.

class MyViewController : UICollectionViewController {

    // recreate the mask after the view lays out it's subviews
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        if let maskImage = createMaskingImage(size: self.view.bounds.size) {
            let maskView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
            maskView.layer.contents = maskImage

            self.view.mask = maskView
        }
    }
}

// create a masking image for a view of the given size
func createMaskingImage(size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {

    let drawingBounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

    // We're going to jump down to the level of cgContext for scaling
    // You might be able to do this from the level of UIGraphics, but I don't know how so...
    // Implicitly unwrapped optional, but if we can't get a CGContext we're in trouble

    let cgContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    let maskingPath = createMaskingPath()
    let pathBounds = maskingPath.bounds;

    cgContext.saveGState()

    // Clearing the image may not strictly be necessary
    cgContext.clear(drawingBounds)

    // Scale the context so that when we draw the path it fits in the drawing bounds
    // Could just use "size" here instead of drawingBounds.size, but I think this makes it a 
    // little more explicit that we're matching up two rects
    cgContext.scaleBy(x: drawingBounds.size.width / pathBounds.size.width,
                      y: drawingBounds.size.height / pathBounds.size.height)
    cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.lightGray.cgColor)
    cgContext.addPath(maskingPath.cgPath)
    cgContext.fillPath(using: .evenOdd)

    cgContext.restoreGState()

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}

func createMaskingPath() -> UIBezierPath {
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 0))
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 162.02, y: 3.8), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 2.1), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 72.57, y: 3.8))
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 324, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 251.48, y: 3.8), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 324, y: 2.1))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 324, y: 150.2))
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 162.02, y: 154), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 324, y: 152.3), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 251.48, y: 154))
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 150.2), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 72.57, y: 154), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 152.3))
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.17), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 148.1), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.17))

    return path
}
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. You have been all over my questions, lol. How would you go about writing this code for a changing size? The content I screen shotted is a `UITableViewCell`. So, the embedded `UICollectionView` changes frames. Override `layoutIfNeeded()` somewhere and draw there?

Comment: OK.  I edited the answer to account for scaling.  Note that I'm scaling the CGPath which means as you scale wider or narrower the "depth" of the ribbon will change.  You could fix this by procedurally changing the ribbon masking shape.

Comment: I should also mention that while I compiled this code in a Playground, I didn't fully run it

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
This is a UICollectionView, which clips normally on the left and right,
but allows some extra space horizontally.
A typical example is you need to clip the scrolling items but you
still need to allow shadows.
*/

import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomClipCollectionView: UICollectionView {

    private lazy var extraSpaceOnBaseButStillClipSidesNormally: CALayer = {
        let l = CALayer()
        l.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        return l
    }()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        extraSpaceOnBaseButStillClipSidesNormally.frame = bounds.insetBy(
                          dx: 0, dy: -10)
        layer.mask = extraSpaceOnBaseButStillClipSidesNormally
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```